# How Consistently Does Alcohol Affect Reaction Times?

Tags: alcohol, cognitive-science, reflex-impulse, blood-alcohol-levels, breathalyzer

I've always been told that alcohol will reduce reaction times.  There are lots of sources for this online.  For example:

> https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2010/10/101019162149.htm
>   http://www.alcoholismrehab.org/research/alcohol-affects-reaction-time/
>   http://www.alcoholismrehab.org/research/alcohol-increases-errors-and-reaction-time-during-decision-making-new-study-shows/

And countless others.  It seems pretty solid.

However, anecdotally, I've noticed a trend where my performance in activities that benefit from a low reaction time improve after I've had a few drinks (namely online FPS games).  I decided to investigate further and setup a small experiment.

**The Experiment**

Every 20 minutes I would record my BAC level using a breathalyzer, take an online reaction time test (http://www.humanbenchmark.com/tests/reactiontime) five times, and consume 1oz of 80 proof alcohol.

For reference, I also consulted an online chart estimating BAC levels (http://bloodalcoholcalculator.org/bac-charts/ - I'm male and ~160 pounds)

The results I saw are completely contradictory to everything I've ever been told.  Over the span of three hours, my reaction time *did not* increase.  In fact, it decreased!  Each point in the chart below is 20 minutes apart - and the estimated BAC level from the website.  And the test consisted of 10 measurements (and I dropped the 2 lowest, 2 highest and averaged the remaining).

[image: BAC Drops over time]

The difference between ~270ms and ~230ms is pretty significant - according to the data collected by the Human Benchmark site I used in my experiment.  At 270ms, my reaction time is right in the most common range.  But as I drank, I ended up way ahead of the curve.

[image: Faster reaction time]

My question is - how can I explain this result?  Everything I find online says alcohol increases reaction time.  I've read studies and I can't disagree with them.  It seems unlikely that I'm some rare abnormality though....so, what's the deal?

Comment: Great question! But I must ask:  How much should we trust the data collection skills of someone who would have been obviously impaired within the first 90 minutes of his experiment?

Comment: You realize practice and motivation decrease reaction time. This seems better suited at CogSci.SE.

Comment: Your experiment does not include any control at all.